# Photoshop - Shape dynamics

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

when I'm using brush tool and I set up Shape dynamics, Control: fade, there's input on the right for fade length.

Is there a way to automatically start fade the path from 50% of length (stroke path)? I don't want to sit and try +10, -10 and so in the input.

Thanks for your time and sorry for my english

Comment: So, I don't know what you are trying accomplish, other than the fade, but after you have drawn the shape, you could take a brush tool ( accompanied with layer mask ) _or_ eraser tool **and** a soft round brush with a healthy size and 0 hardness of course. Then just hide or erase, and you might want to use varying opacity levels depending on the shape of it...

Comment: Maybe this can help to understand the problem: http://melkor.wectory.cz/fade-problem.png

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to start the fade at a specific spot. The fade starts from the end of the stroke inward in all cases.

Comment: ok, thanks, i guess I have to try changing the input value